# CMMotionActivityManager queryActivityStarting in background with location updates

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

First, a little context: my app runs in the background for getting locations, and location updates are active for what's below.

CMMotionActivityManager's queryActivityStarting call returns 0 activities when run in the background, but if my app is active it returns activities for the same time period (the activities exist - they just aren't being returned while in the background).

The startActivityUpdates function works in the background, but I just want the high level activity data from queryActivityStarting without the battery cost of using startActivityUpdates.

Am I mistaken and something else is going on? These 2 functions have very similar signatures, so I'm a little surprised they'd work differently.

---

Edit - asked to show my code.

Here's how I ask for activities - I tried without a delay and with various delays - Apple docs say activities might not be available for several minutes and I didn't know what that meant (anyone have specifics? maybe something else has to happen before activities are available?), so I tried waiting first:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(60 * 60), execute: {
    ModeStorage.sharedInstance.saveModes(tripId, beforeStart, end)
})
```

Here's the code that queries - the last logging line shows a count of 0:

```
guard CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() else { return Log.log("Activity N/A", true) }
CMMotionActivityManager().queryActivityStarting(from:fromDate, to:toDate, to:OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (arr, err) -> Void in
    guard var activities = arr else {return Log.log("modes n/a", true) }
    Log.log("modes save (\(fromDate)-\(toDate): \(activities.count) in \(UIApplication.shared.applicationState.rawValue))", true)
    ...
}
```

---

Another edit: leaving this open as I'd love to use queryActivityStarting, but I switched my code to use startActivityUpdates and that seems to work without a problem.

Comment: Can you show your code; Are you calling begin/end background task when requesting activities?

Comment: I added my code. The code runs fine, I just get 0 activities. I am not using begin/end background task here; if I understand correctly, the background task just lets code run in the background, and this code is already running in the background because of the location updates.

Comment: I think your issue is that the query executes asynchronously and as soon as your location delegate function returns your app will be suspended again. You probably need to let iOS know you are still working by calling `beginBackgroundTask` before the query and ending the background task once the query completes.

Comment: Why would you think that? I'm already successfully running in the background.

Comment: Because you need to understand how iOS schedules your app in the background. Once the called delegate method that was called returns thenios will, suspend your app, even if other asynchronous tasks are still running unless you have told iOS about them. I don't know for sure that this is the problem. It may just be that you can't retrieve activities in the background,

Comment: Tried it; begin/end bg task is not useful here.